# Something is wrong with Maven when I execute the command release:prepare

Tags: java, maven, release, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I've a Maven project using multi-module, when I execute the command release:prepare, happens some problem:

```
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Java\workspace
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unable to tag SCM
Provider message:
The svn tag command failed.
Command output:
svn: E160013: File not found: revision 1065, path '/trunk'
```

Pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>[hidden].logreport</groupId>
    <artifactId>logreport</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>../logreport-client</module>
        <module>../logreport-common</module>
        <module>../logreport-server</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <!-- Timestamp format for the maven.build.timestamp property -->
        <!-- You can reference property in pom.xml or filtered resources (must 
            enable third-party plugin if using Maven < 2.1) -->
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <svn.username>[hidden]</svn.username>
        <svn.password>[hidden]</svn.password>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>[hidden]-releases</id>
            <url>http://[hidden]/nexus/content/repositories/my-releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>[hidden]-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://[hidden]/nexus/content/repositories/my-snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:svn://[hidden]/svn/infra/trunk/logreport/</developerConnection>
        <connection>scm:svn:svn://[hidden]/svn/infra/trunk/logreport/</connection>
        <url>svn://[hidden]/svn/infra/trunk/logreport/</url>
    </scm>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <releaseVersion>0.0.1</releaseVersion>
                    <developmentVersion>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</developmentVersion>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <resume>false</resume>
                    <username>${svn.username}</username>
                    <password>${svn.password}</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If I put th tag `<remoteTagging>false</remoteTagging>` , another problem:

```
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Java\workspace
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unable to tag SCM
Provider message:
The svn tag command failed.
Command output:
svn: E155007: 'C:\Java\workspace' is not a working copy
```

My project is in 'C:\Java\workspace\logreport'.

Tks

Comment: This probably won't help but IME, the release command doesn't work if your project has externs and the error messages are not informative.  Do you have externs in your project?

Comment: Can you show the full folder structure how you called maven and from where you have called maven with which command ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually if you have a multi-module build you should have the following structure:

```
  +-- parent (pom.xml)
       +-- module-1 (pom.xml)
       +-- module-2 (pom.xml)
```

which means also having the parent being located in the trunk of your VCS (in this case SVN).

Furthermore the result of the above structure is that your parent looks similar like this:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.company.logreport</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>logreport-client</module>
    <module>logreport-common</module>
    <module>logreport-server</module>
</modules>
```

and the scm information which will be defined in the parent only once like this:

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:svn://[hidden]/svn/infra/trunk/</developerConnection>
    <connection>scm:svn:svn://[hidden]/svn/infra/trunk/</connection>
    <url>svn://[hidden]/svn/infra/trunk/</url>
</scm>
```

Apart from that you should never define passwords in your pom. The intended place for such things is the [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers).

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>svn-server</id>
      <username>my_login</username>
      <password>my_password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  ...
</settings>
```